# Как добавить в крон wordpress метод экземпляра класса?

Tags: php, wordpress

Пробовал так:

```
class A {
    __construct() {
        this->create_cron_task();
    }

    private function create_cron_task() {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');

        add_action( 'my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly' );
    }

    function do_this_hourly() {
        throw New ErrorException('Test');
    }
}
```

Далее взял плагин WP Crontrol но не вижу там события.

Как сделать вызов метода по времени?

Answer (score 2):

Как и везде в php, метод класса должен быть описан как массив, включающий класс:

```
add_action( 'my_hourly_event', [ $this, 'do_this_hourly' ] );
```

Comment: Попробовал так, событие не создается.

Comment: Потому что это делают один раз, при активации плагина: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_schedule_event